# Central Backup Server For All Hosted Sites

Tags: backup

I host multiple sites from different customers on Ubuntu servers.
I'm thinking about creating a centralised backup solution which would store the data of all these sites (Databases, files uploaded by users etc.) on one central server. The alternatives are

- The server would download the data from multiple application servers
- Multiple application servers would upload their data to the central one

The only problem I've identified with this approach is that if the central backup server were compromised, all data from all projects would be breached. (Although I could encrypt the data in the central backup server with some public key)

Is this a good idea or am I missing something important?

Comment: You're missing how you plan to restore.

Comment: GPG? Just distribute the public key, encrypt the backup before you pull it down/push it over. Just don't loose your private key, keep it safe/offline, you can do all of that with ansible.  I'd also check that you have enough space to make a backup (20GB of data on a 32GB server, you could run out of space and crash your host)

Comment: @JacobEvans Definitely a good idea to encrypt before pulling!

Comment: https://github.com/opsxcq/ansible-role-host-backup

Comment: I find the "backup server per site approach" more secure. All the backup data located on a single backup server makes it a single point of failure in any respect (ransomware, software or hardware failure) Additionally, it complicates the restoration process and data access from those sites. .